# getting javascript variable value from php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

1. My javascript is populating markers on map and for that i need locations ,which i have generated from php file in the format given below
2. i want to dynamically get the result of the php array in the javascript array

```js
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var locations = /// i want here the output as shown below from the php file

    var locations = [["Vidyasagar","28.6139391","77.20902120000005"],
         ["Pushpadantsagar","21.4598","80.195"],
         ["Tarunsagar","28.638","77.2936"],
         ["Samyaktbhushan","20.593684","78.96288000000004"],
         ["Pavitrasagar","23.2836","79.2318"],
         ["Prayogsagar","23.2836","79.2318"],
         ["Arunsagar","30.016","77.4"]];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.2836,79.2318),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
    </script>
```

and the php file is this

```php
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "jainmunilocator";
    $connection=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);;
    if (!$connection) {
         die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $array = array();
    $sql = "SELECT name,id,lat,lng FROM muni_location,munishri WHERE mid=id AND lat<>0";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    $i=0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if(isset($row)){
            $array[$i][0]=$row['name'];
            $array[$i][1]=$row['lat'];
            $array[$i][2]=$row['lng'];
            $i++;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an ajax call.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918462/get-response-from-php-file-using-ajax) is a question on Stack Overflow that has some examples of an ajax call to a php page.

Keep in mind though that you'll need to either include a jQuery library for you to do that, or you can follow along in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) to make an ajax call without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to output the variables into a hidden input field's `value` attribute and encode them as JSON. Then, using Javascript use `JSON.parse` to decode the PHP variables from the hidden input field's value attribute. You can then remove the element from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is by echoing the PHP var into javascript. As Php is processed before, outputting correct Js.

```
<script>
   var locations = array(<?= $VAR ?>);
</script>
```

In this case $VAR must be something like $VAR = "'barcelona','madrid','london'";
Adjust $VAR so it generate correct output. No need to use JSON encode if you just need it for this.