# NEW - JS/HTML/PHP form email submission errors

Tags: php

NEW - discovered that I have a javascript validating and submitting the form on my website - have added the relevant js

Hope someone can help! I am not a coder but stitch together elements to achieve my ends. Have a web form and am using PHP to submit to my email but it is not happening. Email is not sending and the success or failure text is not appearing - Solutions please.

Website is [www.ogracing.eu](http://ogracing.eu/#contact)

**HTML**

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM -->
<div class="col-sm-7 col-md-9">
    <!-- IMPORTANT: change the email address at the top of the php/mail.php file to the email address that you want this form to send to -->
    <form class="form-style validate-form clearfix" action="php/mail.php" method="POST" role="form">
        <!-- form left col -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="text-field form-control validate-field required" data-validation-type="string" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text">
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="text-field form-control validate-field required" data-validation-type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="text-field form-control validate-field required" data-validation-type="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Telephone" name="phone" type="tel">
            </div>
        </div><!-- end: form left col -->
        <!-- form right col -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea placeholder="Message..." class="form-control validate-field required" name="message"></textarea>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <img src="images/loader-form.GIF" class="form-loader">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-inverse">Submit</button>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group form-general-error-container">
                <?php echo $result; ?>
            </div>           
        </div><!-- end: form right col -->
    </form>
</div><!-- end: CONTACT FORM -->
```

**JS** this is only the validate and submit portion of the script - functions.js. I have removed the captcha elemnts from the HTML as I did not want to leave it in - this may or may not be causing a validation issue.

```
function validate_and_submit_forms(b){var a=(b!==undefined&&b.length>0)?b:$("form.validate-form");a.each(function(){var 
c=$(this);c.find(".validate-field").each(function(){$(this).change(function(){$(this).siblings(".alert").fadeOut("fast",function()
{$(this).remove()});if($(this).val().trim()!=""){var e=validate_fields(c,$(this));if(e.length>0){if(e[0]["message"]!==undefined&&e[0]
["message"]!=""&&e[0]["message"]!="success"){var d='<div class="alert">'+e[0]["message"]+"</div>";$(this).after(d);$(this).siblings
(".alert").fadeIn("fast")}}}})});c.find("#form-captcha-refresh").click(function(){reset_captcha(c)});c.submit(function(e)
{e.preventDefault?e.preventDefault():e.returnValue=false;$(this).find(".form-loader").fadeIn("fast");var d=$(this).attr("action");if
(d===undefined&&d==""){return false}$(this).find(".alert").fadeOut("fast",function(){$(this).remove()});$(this).find(".form-general-
error-container").fadeOut("fast",function(){$(this).empty()});var f=false;$(this).find(".validate-field").each(function(){var 
h=validate_fields(c,$(this));if(h.length>0){if(h[0]["message"]!==undefined&&h[0]["message"]!=""&&h[0]["message"]!="success"){var 
g='<div class="alert">'+h[0]["message"]+"</div>";$(this).after(g);$(this).siblings(".alert").fadeIn("fast");f=true}}});if(f==true)
{$(this).find(".form-loader").fadeOut("fast");return false}$.ajax({type:"POST",url:d,data:$(this).serialize
(),dataType:"html",success:function(k){c.find(".form-loader").fadeOut("fast");var l=(k=="success")?true:false;var h=(k=="captcha")?
false:true;var g="";switch(k){case"success":g="Form submitted successfully.";break;case"captcha":g="Incorrect text entered. (Case-
sensitive)";break;case"incomplete":g="Please fill in all required fields.";break;case"error":g="An error occured. Please try again 
later.";break}var j='<div class="alert ';j+=(l==true)?"success":"error";j+='">'+g+"</div>";if(!h){c.find("#form-captcha").parent
(".form-group").append(j);c.find("#form-captcha").siblings(".alert").fadeIn("fast")}else{c.find(".form-general-error-container").html
(j).fadeIn("fast",function(){$(this).delay(10000).fadeOut("fast",function(){$(this).html("")})})}reset_captcha(c);if(l==true){c.find
(".form-control").val("")}},error:function(h){c.find(".form-loader").fadeOut("fast");var g='<div class="alert">An error occured. Please 
try again later.</div>';c.find(".form-general-error-container").html(g).fadeIn("fast")}})})})}function reset_forms(b){if(b!
==undefined&&b.length>0){var a=b;a.find("input").val("");a.find(".alert").remove();a.find(".form-general-error-container").empty
().hide();reset_captcha(b)}}function reset_captcha(b){var a=(b!==undefined&&b.length>0)?b:$("form.validate-form");a.each(function(){var 
e=$(this);var c=e.find("#form-captcha-img");if(c.length>0&&e.is(":visible")){var f=new Date().getTime();c.replaceWith('<img id="form-
captcha-img" src="assets/php/form_captcha/captcha_img.php?t='+f+'" style="display:none">');e.find("#form-captcha").val("");setTimeout
(function(){e.find("#form-captcha-img").show()},500)}})}function validate_fields(d,a){if(d!==undefined&&d.length>0){var b=(a!
==undefined&&a.length>0)?a:d.find(".validate");var c=new Array();b.each(function(){var e=$(this).attr("data-validation-type");var 
h=$(this).hasClass("required");var g=$(this).val().trim();var f=new Array();f.field_object=$(this);f.message="success";if(h==true&&
(g==""||g===null||g===undefined)){f.message="This field is required"}if(e=="string"&&(g!=""&&g!==null&&g!==undefined)){if(g.match(/^[a
-z0-9 .\-]+$/i)==null){f.message="Invalid characters found."}}else{if(e=="email"&&(g!=""&&g!==null&&g!==undefined)){if(g.match(/^
(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]
 +\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)==null){f.message="Please enter a valid email address."}}else{if(e=="phone"&&(g!=""&&g!==null&&g!==undefined))
{if(g.match(/^\(?\+?[\d\(\-\s\)]+$/)==null){f.message="Invalid characters found."}}}}c.push(f)});return c}}function 
contact_form_IE9_placeholder_fix(){var a=$("form");a.each(function(){var b=$(this);$(this).find(".form-control").each(function(){var 
c=$(this).attr("placeholder");if(c!==undefined&&c!=""){$(this).val(c);$(this).focus(function(){if($(this).val()==c){$(this).val
("")}});$(this).blur(function(){if($(this).val()==""){$(this).val(c)}})}})})}function change_bg_check(){return
((jQuery.browser.mobile&&background_settings.change_on_mobile)||(!jQuery.browser.mobile&&background_settings.change_on_nonmobile))?
true:false}function tabs_uniform_height(){var g=$(".tabpanel.uniform-height");for(var f=0,a=g.length;f<a;f++){var e=0;var h=$(g
[f]).find(".tab-pane");for(var d=0,b=h.length;d<b;d++){var c=$(h[d]).attr("style");$(h[d]).css
({position:"absolute",visibility:"hidden",display:"block"});e=($(h[d]).outerHeight(true)>e)?$(h[d]).outerHeight(true):e;$(h[d]).attr
("style",c?c:"")
}h.css({"min-height":e+"px"})}};
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'race@ogracing.eu'; 
    $subject = 'Message from website ';
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Telephone: $phone\n message:\n $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

     //Check if telephone number has been entered
    if (!$_POST['phone']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter a telephone number';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail  && !$errPhone && !$errMessage) {
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        }
        else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Update**

I have found some responses from my mail.php - shown below. These are appearing in a window within firebug!!

**Response headers**

- Content-Length   0
- Content-Type     text/html
- Date             Fri, 21 Aug 2015 11:14:10 GMT
- Server           Microsoft-IIS/8.5
- X-Powered-By-Plesk   PleskWin
- x-powered-by     ASP.NET

**Request headers**

- Accept   text/html, */*; q=0.01
- Accept-Encoding  gzip, deflate
- Accept-Language  en,en-US;q=0.5 Content-Length   69
- Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
- Cookie   _ga=GA1.2.1848665366.1439996290
- DNT  1 Host  www.ogracing.eu
- Referer  http://www.ogracing.eu/
- User-Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0 X-
- Requested-With   XMLHttpRequest

**Post**

- email    aidan@pulce.co.uk
- message  more
- name Aidans analytics
- phone    56
- Source name=Aidans+analytics&email=aidan%40pulce.co.uk&phone=56&message=more

**HTML**
Nothing Nada and Nix - guess this is part of the problem

**Cookies**
are being sent

So it appears we are not generating any HTML for the email thus it is not being sent. Any more help and advice is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Everything should work. Maybe you have a php error in other part of your mail.php file. You can check your log files to find out it.

Comment: `if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from))` May be an issue?? why are you doing an if statement on the mail send?

Comment: @JoshuaNightingale The mail() function returns true or false depending on if it succeeds, so in this case, for example, the if statement is used to display a success or error message on the page.

Comment: Show the rest of your code, it's hard to say what's wrong with only a small bit of it.

Comment: @ DanielV - I do not know what the error is.  The response appears as a white box on the website but there is no visible text. Using firebug I see the detail from the filled in form but it fails to send.

Comment: @ Harris the php file is all that I have - I did include a link to the website should you have enough time to look there.

Comment: To all of you who have commented - I am humbled that the web society gives so much time and effort for nothing.

Comment: There is some of the php file missing  - for some reason it is not displaying have tried editing it but it is the first 6 lines                      <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'race@ogracing.eu'; 
    $subject = 'Message from website ';

Comment: You do not have any form element named `submit`, so you can’t expect `$_POST["submit"]` to be set either.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for that info but exactly what do I type and where?? TIA

Comment: You need to set a `name` attribute on your submit button.

Comment: @CBroe have set the name attribute on the submit button and have updated the file above but it still does not work.

Comment: Well then you’ll need to do some more debugging, to find out what your code does (and doesn’t.) Add debug outputs to see which if/else branches are stepped into, control the values of variables via `var_dump`, etc.

Comment: You're not actually `echo`ing the `$result` anywhere which is why it's not appearing.

Comment: @harris - there is a line at the end of the php "<?php echo $result; ?>" this is in a div container in the HTML file

Comment: @Aidan Ah so it is, but it won't do much, since when you're loading the main page `$result` is not defined. It only exists in `mail.php` when the form is submitted.

Comment: So @harris what do I do and where please. Considering going back to square one with this project!!

Comment: Your JavaScript is a pain to read, but apparently you're submitting the form via Ajax. You need to make `mail.php` echo the responses and then handle those responses in the Ajax call. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918462/get-response-from-php-file-using-ajax

Comment: This of course doesn't solve the problem of the mail not being sent, which is something you might need to debug server-side.

Answer (score 0):

In the `PHP` code that you have posted you have this:

```
if (!$errName && !$errEmail  && !$errPhone && !$errMessage)
```

But the `$errPhone` variable is not declared anywhere. Probably in your log file you will find a notice:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: $errPhone in file_path/file_name.php on line...
```

And giving that you said *"the success or failure text is not appearing"* I can say that the error is there, because due to the `Notice`, your nested `if` is never executed.

If you don't have a log file try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your script and you will see the error directly on your page.

To give you a solution, you must also check the existence of `$_POST["phone"]` and declare a variable `$errPhone` (as you did for the other fields `name`,`email` and `message`) to allow the `if` statement to return `true` and continue with the execution.

Moreover, as [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066805/html-php-form-email-submission-errors#comment52098542_32066805), you must give a name to your submit button:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-inverse">Submit</button>
```

In this way you'll have `$_POST['submit']` available in your `PHP` script.

Comment: Thanks Cliff - will give it a try and decode what you have actually said and get back to you.

Comment: You are welcome @Aidan - if you have any problem understanding, I can try to write it in Spanish. I am Italian and our languages are similar **;)**

Comment: have tried your suggestions and edited the code above to show changes - still no luck. No need for Spanish - english mother tongue.

Comment: @Aidan ahah ok, so I'm not too able to talk in english, sorry XD Anyway, in your updated code, inside the `if(!$_POST["phone"])` you have a typo: You are declaring `$errMessage` instead of `$errPhone`, so the `$errPhone` variable is still not available.