# PHP wrong response with AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with the response of PHP using AJAX POST.

My PHP code is this one:

```
$vadb_dsn = 'odbc:DSN=VerticaDSNunixodbc;Database=DB';
$vadb_options = array(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT=>FALSE, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$vadb_user = 'dbadmin';
$vadb_pass = 'dbpwd';

$user=$_POST['user'];
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];


# Connect to Database
try {
    $vadb = new PDO( $vadb_dsn, $vadb_user, $vadb_pass, $vadb_options );
}
catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Couldn't connect to DB" );
}

# Query to Database
$vsql = "SELECT user_name as 'user_name', password as 'password' from schema.table where user_name='".$user."' and password='".$pwd."';";

# Prepare Statement and Execute
$stmt = $vadb->prepare( $vsql );
$stmt->execute();

# Fetch Results
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $result = $row['user_name'].";".$row['password'];
}

# Close Connection
$vadb = null;

# Output the result
echo $result
```

when I execute the POST, in this way:

```
var url = "example.php"; 
var user= $('#user').val();
var pwd= $('#pwd').val();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: $("#formpost").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
   success: function(data)
   {
       alert(data); // show response from the php script.
   }
});
```

I get, as response from PHP file, instead of the query result, the code of PHP file itstelf. 
In other words, my webpage prompts an alert in wich the content is the php file code...
any ideas on how to solve this and get the proper response?

Comment: Does the PHP script (unto itself) run the query when called directly?

Comment: If you are getting php code on page use <?php at top of page.

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918462/get-response-from-php-file-using-ajax) option?

Comment: yes, when called by shell, the php file responses correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you have PHP installed? What happens if you create a file called `index.php` and put in `<?php echo "TEST"; ?>` inside of it, then load it in the browser?

Comment: yes, php is installed. I tested expample.php by command line with the command: php example.php

Comment: Just because you tested it on the command line does not mean it's the same PHP instance that apache is using, FYI. Make sure it's working by loading an index.php file in your root directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved reinstalling php on the server (Centos), so in this case, from shell:

```
yum install php
```

and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<?php` at the top of the PHP file. It looks like you're missing this in the PHP you pasted.

If you're getting php code itself, you're just getting the contents of the file. It looks like you're missing the pre-processor tag.

If that doesn't work, try changing the URL to '/example.php' instead of 'example.php'

Comment: the <?php tag is present..

Comment: try adding a / before example.php to make it `/example.php`

Comment: nope, same result...

Comment: Try doing `print_r` on the array called $result to ensure you are actually getting output you expected.