# Why php ajax is not giving any response?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on my college project, In that i have a webpage which is supposed to display City and temperature, I am trying to use AJAX to update temperature at some intervals.
Here's the code

for ajax request Java Script, I saw this code in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18243161/4341530

```
function postAjaxRequest(qry){
alert("Ajax response on " +qry);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_resp.php",
data: {q: qry},
dataType:'JSON', 
success: function(response){
    dispatchCallBack(qry,response);
}});}
```

the `alert("Ajax response on " +qry);` is working fine so I know this code is running. But when I put this kind of "alert()" just before `dispatchCallBack(qry,response);` its not working, so I infer here that the request is not successful.

Here's `ajax_resp.php`

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['q'])&&!empty($_POST['q'])
{
    if($_POST['q']=="c_temp")
    {
        $api_key = "Here's my api key, working alright"; 
        $city_id = "here's city id, also working correct";
        $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=".$city_id."&APPID=".$api_key;

        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $json_o = json_decode($json);

        $city_name =  $json_o->city->name;
        $temp_c =  $json_o->list[0]->main->temp-273;
        echo json_encode(array("city"=>$city_name,"temp"=>$temp));
//I have checked JSON response seperately its correct. I was able to get city name and temperature variable properly initialised.
    }
}?>
```

so I can't figure out what's wrong. I am newbie :p May be some silly mistake, would be greatfull if pointed out.

Comment: add `.catch` callback and see if it fails

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: begin by opening the browser's developer tools, watch the network activity.
this will let you know if the issue is on the client side or the server.
if it's a server issue then you'll see the error response.
if it's a client then no request will come out at all.

Comment: this `$_POST[q]` should be `$_POST['q']`

Comment: and you'd need to assign `$qry= $_POST['q'];` first

Comment: OK, thanks for mentioning, I've changed it to : `if(isset($_POST['q'])&&!empty($_POST['q'])`  and `if($_POST['q']=="c_temp")` though still not solves the problem

Comment: Do yourself a favor, simply place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely in the developer tools to make sure you have actually sent what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the code below and correct them

[1] use single quotes or double quotes to get data from `$_POST` variable having the string index

[2] `$qry` is not defined earlier. After reading the question the most probable value of the $qry can be $_POST['q']. So replace `$qry` with `$_POST['q']` or assign `$qry = $_POST['q']`

```
if(isset($_POST['q'])&&!empty($_POST['q'])
{
if($_POST['q']=="c_temp") <==  $_POST['q'] instead of $qry
{
    $api_key = "Here's my api key, working alright"; 
    $city_id = "here's city id, also working correct";
    $url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=".$city_id."&APPID=".$api_key;

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_o = json_decode($json);

    $city_name =  $json_o->city->name;
    $temp_c =  $json_o->list[0]->main->temp-273;
    echo json_encode(array("city"=>$city_name,"temp"=>$temp));
    //I have checked JSON response seperately its correct. I was able to get city name and temperature variable properly initialised.
}
}?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard does that sound good ?

Comment: Ok, I've made changes, I think I was planning to use $qry but missed it, anyways, Still the same, any other suggestions, anything else wrong with the code ?

Comment: @Salim write `console.log(response)` to see what is returned from the php file

Comment: Actually if I delete all the php code and just hard code `echo json_encode(array("city"=>"London","temp"=>32));` then too it doesn't works

Comment: @Salim  var_dump($_POST) to see what you are sending to the page and use console.log(response) in the success function to see what you get from the php page