# PHP : get response fro $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to fetch data based on ajax call

this is  my code to get the id

```
<h3> <a class='click' data-id='<?=$rows["id"];?>'><?=$rows['title'];?></a</h3>
```

This is my jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".click").on('click',function() {                
      var id= $(this).attr("data-id"); 
      alert(id);

      $.ajax({     
        type: "POST",
        url: "getevents.php", 
        data: {id:id}, 
        dataType: "html",                  
        success: function(response){                    
            console.log(response); 

        }
     });
 })})  
</script>
```

**getevents.php**

```
 <? 
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        echo  $_POST['id'] ; 
    }

    $singleevent = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `id`=."'$id'"  ') or die('error');
    while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($link , $singleevent)){
            print_r($row); 
    }

  ?>
```

**$_POST['id'];** gets printed in console but not the response . i tried echo and print_r() both in while loop but nothing is in response .

Please help me with this

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of the developer tools to see what was sent and what was returned? Are you connecting to the database and just shortening the code for us in getevents.php?

Comment: For one thing, there's no need for a `while` loop *and* a `print_r()`.

Comment: Along with the other things mentioned, there's a syntax error in your query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918462/get-response-from-php-file-using-ajax read this

Comment: you should have used error reporting; undefined variable.

Comment: @PatrickQ Lordie, that took me a while to spot it *lol!*.

Comment: where is `$link` and `$id` also test by replacing `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` and put id in url like `xyz.com?id=1`

Comment: check your errors first, error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Check out my answer here and don't worry that the question is about IIS and ASP, the methodology for debugging AJAX is the same regardless of your server-side technology, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533285/why-the-ajax-script-is-not-running-on-iis-7-5-win-2008-r2-server/21617685#21617685

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your PHP. First, you forget to reassign the variable, then you improperly concatenate the variable in your query. You also probably do not want the query to run if the id is not set, so you need to re-arrange your brackets:

```
<? 
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id =  $_POST['id'] ; // set the variable for the query
        $singleevent = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `id` = $id") or die('error');
        $row=  mysqli_fetch_array($singleevent, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        print_r($row); 
    }
?>
```

I am assuming that your `$link` is a good and correct connection to your database. You also do not need a while loop, assuming that the id selects a single row of data. You also need to fetch the array properly, using the result of the query and `MYSQLI_ASSOC` like this:

```
$row=  mysqli_fetch_array($singleevent, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Which I have included in the code block.

### NOTE

If PHP short tags are not enabled you will need to change `<?` to `<?php`

### WARNING

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Just one small point here.  If you're going to use `isset()` as the check instead of `empty()` (and I'm not arguing that choice, since 0 could be a valid id value), then you really should parameterize or quote the value in the query.  It is possible for the parameter to be sent, but empty, which would break the query the way you have it now.

Comment: You're correct, which is why I included the warning @PatrickQ. I expect the id is an integer of some sort, so didn't get overly worried about it.

Comment: Okay, but I wouldn't consider an empty value to be an SQL injection attack.  I really don't want to be _that guy_, but with the (perfectly valid) comments you left on the other answers, I would have expected a more robust answer, that actually _shows_ the right way to do it, not just saying that the way presented is not safe. /steps down from soapbox

Comment: FWIW @PatrickQ I debated in my head whether or not to rewrite the OP's code and then took into consideration his rep, which means he has been around the block a little, before deciding to provide the essentials and including the information to make it all correct. This stems from a discussion on META about code rewrites. I appreciate your comments.