# How to check if a username is already taken with ajax and sql?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to check if a username exists in the db with ajax. I don't know why it doesn't work i tried many things and still get nothing.

this is the code that i'm actually trying. the php code works but doesn't send the result to the ajax function

html >Registration.php

```
<input class="form-control" onblur="checkUser()" id="Pseudo" type="text name="Pseudo" value="" required>" 
 <span id="availability" name="availability" value="">  </span>
```

php >Welcome.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['Pseudo']))
{

    $pseudo = $_POST['Pseudo'];

    $connexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

        if(!$connexion)
        {
            die('Error during connexion ');
        }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Web_database WHERE Pseudo='$pseudo'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connexion, $sql);
    echo  mysqli_num_rows($result);

}
```

Javascript  > Registration.php

```
    function checkUser()
    {
        var Pseudo = $('#Pseudo').val();

          $.ajax({
            url:'Welcome.php',
            method:"POST",
            data:{Pseudo:Pseudo},

             success:function(data)
             {
                  if(data == '0')
                    { 
                       $('#availability').html('Pseudo correcte');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#availability').html('Pseudo déja utilisé');
                    }

            }


    });
```

}

Comment: Did you checked what is the value being passed to the server through browser developer tools. All the ajax/backend calls will be recorded in network tab of browser console. Just check whether the value is getting passed to the server call and let us know

Comment: Regardless of it working or not, taking input straight from the request and putting it into an sql statement is a **very bad** idea, and is subject to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can probably optimize your SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Web_database WHERE Pseudo='$pseudo'"
```

Instead of using `mysqli_num_rows()`.

[You are also opening yourself up to SQL injection unless you use prepared statements.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

As for your AJAX, it doesn't seem to be wrong. [I found this question to be very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918462/get-response-from-php-file-using-ajax) so you might want to check that out. When in doubt, `console.log()` the response from PHP to see what's actually being returned. Or better yet, [add a breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints).

Comment: Agreed, and I'd suggest PDO as the best solution