# Request PHP file data with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use an ajax request on a php file hosted on an URL. And i can't retrive datas from it.

My code :

Ajax request :

```
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://urltomysite.com/api/discogs/search.php",
  datatype: "html",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

Php file :

```
<?php
echo 'i am a string';
?>
```

the console log just returns nothing.

Is someone have an idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Where does `dataString` come from? Is it actually running your PHP or not?

Comment: `data:datastring` is of no use here for just this test. Click the `F12` key to [reveal the browser's developer tools](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html). Look for the Network tab, then try the AJAX request. You should see what is sent and what is returned.

Comment: OK so i remove the parameter "data: dataString" and i see the ajax request in network from developer tool. But the request status is fail ...

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? What's the error message assigned to that failing request?

Comment: it's apparently a problem with CORS.

Comment: If it's CORS here's what you need then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work as detailed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918462/get-response-from-php-file-using-ajax).

```
<?php echo 'apple'; ?> is pretty much literally all you need on the
server.
```

and

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://urltomysite.com/api/discogs/search.php",
  data: queryParams,
  success: function(data) {
   alert(data); // apple
  }
});
```

You can also simplify with [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get). There might be other things like Same-Origin policy at play here if you're requesting a page from another domain. This will usually mean that you need to add [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header to your API. That would depend on the server specifics. And there is no info about it here. So I would assume nginx. This would mean adding `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'requesting origin domain';` to your config. More about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Another solution is to add the header within PHP script for example:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: client.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer instead of linking to other questions

Comment: Your're right it's a problem with CORS but how to resolve this error ?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i have on the server side ...

Comment: @NicoHaase fixed the answer, could you remove the downvote?

Comment: @jcalcada-atoswap seperate origins?

Comment: yes seperate origins : ``` Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.tools.urltomysite.net/api/discogs/search.php' from origin 'http://www.urltomysite.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. ```

Comment: If you don't control the urltomysite.net you cannot use the API. @jcalcada-atoswap, also added sample config.

Comment: @fsacer I haven't downvoted your answer

Comment: @fsacer urltomysite is my site. what do you mean about don't control the urltomysite.net

Comment: @jcalcada-atoswap what server software are you using? I was assuming nginx in answer

Comment: @fsacer i don't know it's hosted by OVH.com

Comment: btw i can request my url with postman and i have the response

Comment: @jcalcada-atoswap makes sense, yeah that works cause you're another browser not crossing origin. So I guess you can't control the config. I added a PHP way.